# menu as fragment android developement

Tags: android, fragment, development-environment

i'm trying to create a menu using fragments so I can reuse my fragment on all my activity's, the code seems to work fine and I don't get any errors but whenever I run the emulator and try to use the menu it crashes. Here's my code.

navigation_bar_fragment.xml

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center"

    >



    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hem"
        android:id="@+id/Home_Button"
        android:onClick="homeOnClick"
        />
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sök"
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:onClick="searchOnClick"
        />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Kamera"
        android:id="@+id/camera"


        />

    />
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Recept"
        android:id="@+id/recepies"

        />


</RadioGroup>
```

NavigationBarFragment.java
Here I try to go to HomePage activity when I press on the home button.

```
public class NavigationBarFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //Define that this class will use the navigation_bar_fragment xml file for the layout
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.navigation_bar_fragment, container, false);


    return view;
}

public void homeOnClick (View view){


    Intent homePage = new Intent(NavigationBarFragment.this.getActivity(), HomePage.class);
    NavigationBarFragment.this.startActivity(homePage);
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: In what activity do you call this fragment ? Also, the 'homeOnClick' and the 'searchOnClick' methods need to be in the activity.

Comment: I call them in the main activity, so do I need to have the homeOnClick and searchOnClick on every activity that uses this fragment?

Comment: Yes, those methods need to go in the parent activity.

Comment: I added the code to the main activity but I'm still ecnountering the same problem, the app crashes.

Comment: Okay, it'd be great if you could add your logcat trace